# Why VMware Player does not recognize USB devices?

Tags: windows-7, usb, ubuntu-10.04, vmware-player

I am running **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS** as a guest OS via **VMware Player 3.1.4 build-385536** over **Windows 7 Home Premium** host OS. This runs on a HP Pavilion g7-1173dx laptop.

At the `Virtual Machine... menu` > `VM Settings...` dialog I see a `USB Controller` present in the Device list. In the Connections frame, the `USB 2.0 device` support in enabled.

However, on the `Virtual Machine...` menu > `Removable Devices` submenu I see no USB device entry.

Attaching a Sandisk Cruzer 16GB flash drive to the USB port, I can see the drive in Windows, but I can't see the device in the VM list.

Trying to connect an Altera FPGA dev board system to the USB port was not successful either.

When restarting the VM, I get the following error tooltip:

[image]

Other than that port, I have a USB keyboard and a USB mouse connected to the other 2 USB ports, both working well.

How can I make VMware Player recognize my USB devices?

**EDIT 1:**

Thanks to @Moab, I found out that the relevant service was indeed inactive. Its Startup type is "Automatic". I tried to manually start it and received the following error:

[image]

I am not sure what this means. The drive (configured as a U3 drive, BTW) is recognized in Windows.

**EDIT 2:**

Found [this post](http://kb.VMware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1016809) on the VMware Knowledgebase. It suggests that on AMD based systems (like my g7) there may be a conflict with some `AMD USB Driver Filter`, and provides with removal instructions and a warning that it may disable other USB devices.

How safe is it to follow the steps suggested in the post?

Comment: Maybe you need to run VMware Player AS Administrator?

Comment: Maybe try running this VM in the evaluation version of VMware Workstation.

Comment: Check Windows Services and be sure VMware USB Arbitration Service is running, as the error message suggests.

Comment: @Moab - many thanks. The service was on "Automatic", but not started. When trying to start it manually, I get an error message. I will update the question.

Comment: I never consider anything safe, this is why I have backups of my system and critical personal data.. Make a full disk image pr two for disaster recovery purposes and then make a manual Windows restore point before you make any changes.

Comment: @Moab - you are right in this approach. Fortunately, this is a 2 days old computer which I did not have much chance yet to "personalize", so restoring its initial condition from the preinstalled image will not be too painful.

Comment: VMware USB Arbitration Service was automatic but wasn't running. Once I started it, restarted my VM, I got it recognised.

Comment: @saintjab which means a link here will be helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/291611/vmware-player-does-not-display-usb-stick-and-can-not-connect-to-network#comment859915_291627

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the problem seems to be a collision of the `VMware USB Arbiter` service with the `AMD USB Filter Driver`. I used the method described in [section 5](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1016809) to remove the filter driver using the AMD Catalyst uninstall wizard.

After removing the filter and restarting everything, a USB drive is now recognized and mounted by VM. I was able to play a MP3 file from the drive.

Note that as of now, I have not yet tested for any side-effects of the USB operation on the Win 7 system. Per the reference, there might be problems using USB devices after removing the filter.