# Using FTDI device with Ubuntu on VMware virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, usb, ubuntu-10.04, vmware-player

[Now that I can connect a USB devices to Ubuntu on VMware Player on Win 7](https://superuser.com/questions/343049/why-vmware-player-does-not-recognize-usb-devices), I tried to use my Altera FPGA dev board. This board contains a FTDI bridge allowing it to connect to the PC via a USB port. Once the cable is connected, I see the `Altera USB device` icon active on the VMware device list.

From the Ubuntu terminal I run some configuration steps to mound the device, etc. Then I try to start the gdb debugger server (which runs the executable on the target DSP hardware). I then get the following message:

`Initializing FTDI USB Controller...

Open and Initialize USB Port...

ftdi_usb_get_strings failed: -7 (error sending control message: Connection timed out)

Can't open or initialize usb deviceCan't init USB device, check cable connection  Bailing out!`

(Cable connection is OK)