# Why my Vmware can not connect USB camera?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, vmware, vmware-workstation, camera

**Background:** Hello, guys. I am trying to collect images from a USB camera. My environment is Ubuntu 16.04 in the Vmware Workstation 12 and Win10. My laptop has 2 USB 3.0 interfaces and the camera with USB 2.0. Unfortunately, I meet some strange questions.

**Desriptions**: **Sometimes** I met that USB camera could not be distinguished by the vmware. It is confused that I can not control the occasion whether USB camera can connect the vmware. I am sure that the USB configuration of vmware is USB 2.0 and the camera can work well both in win10 and Ubuntu (Well, sometimes it can not be connected with the vmware) . Besides, I can connect the camera of laptop itself and other USB device such as a USB flash disk.

PS: I have tried almost all the methods I could find to deal with this question such as the vmtools reinstallion, vmware repair and even vmware reinstallation.

Anyone says some advices? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why VMware Player does not recognize USB devices?](https://superuser.com/questions/343049/why-vmware-player-does-not-recognize-usb-devices)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I see the link but I think the problem between that author and me are little different. First my laptop is in Intel not AMD; Second I check the VM USB service and other VM services and they are all in the automatic state. I am confused that my USB flash driver can always be connected with VMware but the USB camera can not. The connection of the camera maybe have a luck