# Connecting USB on virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, usb, virtual-machine

I remove manually USB flash from the host and right click and connect it to virtual machine, but after a while it shows me:

> The connection fot the USB device "Apacer USB Mass Storage Device" was unsuccessful.

I use Win 7 ultimate as host and also my virtual machine, I installed VM tools and  I tried to disable and enable it from my virtual Machine's side. My VMware version: Pro.14.1.1

Comment: Did you try to restart the vm-guest ? Or maybe look to the partitions with Diskpart, inside your Windows-vm ?

Comment: Dear @Tech-IO  Yes, I did restart the vm-guest. what do you mean by "Diskpart"? actually the USB in device manager inside the VM machine is not recognized and I don't see any change neither after enable/disable it from VM machine nor connect/disconnect it from Host side!

Comment: You may also check the usb-controller settings https://superuser.com/questions/291611/vmware-player-does-not-display-usb-stick-and-can-not-connect-to-network. Diskpart is a Partioning tool in Windows. Sometimes it happens that a usb device is not recognized(assigned), so that it needs to be assigned, to show it in the explorer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer! The only thing that I should have done for each machine, was to assign **USB compatibility** for each VM to USB 2.0 which already was USB 3.0 by default.
And of course if I also would like to use my USB 3.0 physical ports, I must change the setting to USB 3.0 via this directory:

> menu > VM > Settings > USB controller > Connections > USB Compatibility: USB 3.0